# Can I make item's item.cost will be the product.price * produce.quantity when I create table

Tags: sql, plsql, nested-table

I want the item's item.cost will be the produce.price * produce.quantity..

How can I do it when I the table item??

There is my SQL code:

```
create or replace type Product as Object(
product_code char(6);
product_name varchar2(6);
description clot(500);
price number(6,2);
constraint uniq_product_code primary key(product_code)
);
/

CREATE TYPE Products IS TABLE OF Product;

CREATE or replace type object Item  as Object(
item_code char(6);
quantity number(6);
cost number(11,2);
products Product;
constraint uniq_item_code primary key(item_code)
);
NESTED TABLE products STORE AS item_product;
/

Create  type Items is Table of Item;

CREATE or replace TYPE Contact_detail AS OBJECT (
   email    varchar2(30);
   address  VARCHAR2(50);
   telephone   varchar2(20);
);
/

Create or replace table Order(
order_number char(6);
order_name varchar2(6);
customer_contact_details Contact_detail;
date date;----
Items Item;
constraint uniq_order_number primary key(order_number)
);
NESTED TABLE Items STORE AS order_item;
/
```

In addation, I will make a PL/SQL to allow the user to input information from a user to insert into Order table. How to automically detect the amount of the items. the amount n, 2<=n<=10.

Comment: Really good question since your example data format does not include product_price or produce_quantity.  I think you should fix the question so it makes sense.

Comment: product_price and produce_quantity are the price and quantity attribute in object product

Comment: Why? You can calculate it on the fly and should do so...

Answer (score 0):

Add a member function to the Item object type to calculuate the value.